# Django and uwsgi not playing nicely (tupleobject: bad argument to internal function)

Tags: python, django, uwsgi

A few days ago, out of the blue I started getting lots of Bad Gateway errors from my django application. In the logs I'm intermittently seeing these lines:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/var/www/site/environ/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/wsgi.py", line 240, in __call__
    from django.conf import settings
SystemError: ../Objects/tupleobject.c:142: bad argument to internal function
site [pid: 30075|app: 0|req: 133/415] 65.55.215.78 () {38 vars in 505 bytes} [Mon May 20 03:20:45 2013] GET /robots.txt => generated 0 bytes in 2 msecs (HTTP/1.1 500) 0 headers in 0 bytes (0 switches on core 0)
```

I can't seem to find anyone online who's diagnosed the cause of this. Mostly people get fed up and move to a different wsgi server.

Has anyone else here seen this error or know what causes it?

#### EDIT: VERSION

```
$ uwsgi --version
uWSGI 1.0.3-debian
```

Acording to @roberto, this "ancient" version is likely my problem.

Comment: check your settings. you might have missed something trivial there - example - `(obj)` instead of `(obj, )` etc

Answer (score 0):

it is not easy to understand what is going on without details (like uwsgi config and python version or the list of third party modules used in the django apps). By the way are you sure you are not using some ancient (read: broken) uWSGI version like everything < 1.2.8 ? Those kind of errors could happens on reference count bugs. But it could be a threading problems too, so paste your config :)

Comment: Ubuntu 13.04 comes with `1.2.3-debian` in the standard repos. Where should I go for a PPA with the latest version?

Comment: install via pip, the currently available debian packages are incredibly old. There are updated packages in unstable debian, but installing via pip ensure you a stable release (uWSGI is a single binary file and build in 30 seconds, packages are not so vital)

Comment: Installing via pip... the question is whether it will install everything to the correct system locations...

Comment: there is no "everything", uWSGI is a single file, what debian/ubuntu does (or better, did, as newer packages will use the blessed approach) is an over-engineerization. Just remove uwsgi packages (but not the config files of your apps) and install it with pip. Now simply run uwsgi <config> for each app or use the Emperor. But for now i would focus on checking if the bug is solved.